# "Ask Ubuntu requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."

Tags: support

I'm using the chromium browser. I keep getting the error "Ask Ubuntu requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load." What settings should I be checking?

Comment: This was happening to me a bit yesterday, make sure you clean your cache and do a ctrl-f5 to load it up, cleared it up for me.

Comment: @Jorge Castro It worked, thanks!

Comment: Yes, @Jorge that worked for me. Thanks

Comment: A Ctrl+Shift+R is better on some browsers and platforms.

Answer (score 7):

The source of the page has a few clues...

```
href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/askubuntu/img/favicon.ico"
href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/askubuntu/img/apple-touch-icon.png"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"
src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=118154f2a0c5"
href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/askubuntu/all.css?v=1c6ec0c47668"
```

Answer (score 0):

After the latest `NoScript` update (https://noscript.net/?ver=2.6.9.29&prev=2.6.9.27), needed to allow `ajax.googleapis.com` to be able to do *anything* on the site (upvoting, commenting, etc).

Not sure though whether this is due to said update or a concurrent change on SX.

<sub>The above applies to Firefox (and NoScript) ...</sub>

---

Further reading:

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

> The Google **Hosted Libraries** is a stable, reliable, high-speed,
>   globally available content distribution network for the most popular,
>   open-source JavaScript libraries.
>
> Google works directly with the key stakeholders for each library
>   effort and accepts the latest versions as they are released.
>
> Libraries
>
> To load a hosted library, copy and paste the HTML snippet for that
>   library (shown below) in your web page. For instance, to load jQuery,
>   embed the `<script
>   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`
>   snippet in your web page.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

> One big advantage of using the hosted **jQuery** from Google or Microsoft:
>
> Many users already have downloaded jQuery from Google or Microsoft
>   when visiting another site. As a result, it will be loaded from cache
>   when they visit your site, which leads to faster loading time. Also,
>   most CDN's will make sure that once a user requests a file from it, it
>   will be served from the server closest to them, which also leads to
>   faster loading time.

http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

> (...) I urge you to use the Google HostedLibraries content delivery
>   network to serve **jQuery** to your users directly from Google’s network
>   of datacenters. Doing so has several advantages over hosting jQuery on
>   your server(s): **decreased latency, increased parallelism,** and **better
>   caching**.